# Factors/divisibility of monotonically-increasing integer polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, polynomials, divisibility

For positive integers $n$ and $x$, let $f_n(x)$ be a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n-1$, such that $f_n(x)$ is monotonically increasing for increasing $x \ge 1$.

Now assume that there exist positive integers $k$ and $d$ such that
\begin{align}
f_n(16k+2) = (4k+1)d \qquad\text{and}\qquad f_n(16k+3) = (8k+1)d.
\end{align}

With no other information, can anything be determined about $f_n(x)$ or $k$ or $d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only interesting case is $n=3$.  $n=1$ is vacuous, since there are no monotonic increasing polynomials of degree zero. For $n=2$ we can solve everything, yielding 
$$
f_2(x) = 4kd\,x +d(1-4k-64k^2)
$$

For $n=3$, let $f_3(x) = a_2x^2+a_1s+a_0$.  Then subtracting the two given equations we obtain
$$
a_1 = 4kd - (32k+5)a_2
$$
which then lets us obtain
$$
f_3(x) = a_2 x^2 + [4kd-(32k+5)a_2]x + [(256k^2+80k+6)a_2-d(64k^2+4k-1)]
$$
So there is for a given $k$ and $d$ a 1-parameter family of polynomials that work, but we mjust start with a large enough leading coefficient, since the derivative, at $x=1$, needs to be positive:
$$
a_2 > \frac{4d}{32k+7}
$$

For $n>3$ the two equations seriously under-determine the $m$ coefficients, and the problem becomes uninteresting again.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks. Out of curiosity, if $(16k+3)^m \mid d$ for some integer $m$ "fairly close to $n-1$" (e.g., $n-3$), would you be able to determine a lot more? (I'm currently working on proving that statement, and making it more precise, which is why I don't really feel right putting it in the full question.)